# Why does the getattr(quizform, 'ans1') fail when quizform.ans1 works while accessing a dynamically created form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am generating a form for answers to a quiz. Since the answers will be different for each quiz, I am creating a dynamic form depending on the quiz. The quiz is stored in a dictionary.

I am creating form fields as:

```
forms.py:
class QuizForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, quiz, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuizForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        chdict = {}
        for num in range (1, 11):
            ch = 'choices'+str(num)
            chdict[ch] = []
            for j in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'):
                chstr = j + str(num)
                chdict[ch].append((chstr, quiz[chstr]))
            ansstr = 'ans'+str(num)
            quesstr = 'ques'+str(num)
            self.fields[ansstr] = forms.ChoiceField(label=quesstr, choices=chdict[ch], widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

In templates, I do a getattr on the quizform, which gives AttributeError:

```
template/quiz.html: <snippet>
    {% for i in num %}   <<< where num = ('1','2','3',...)
        <post question>
        {% with "ans"|add:i as ans %}
            {{ quizform|getattribute:ans }} <<< I can access quizform.ans1 here directly, but getattr in template filter fails 
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
```

getattribute is a template filter:

```
@register.filter('getattribute')
def getattribute(f, name):
    if hasattr(f, name):           <<< I get AttributeError here. 
        return getattr(f, name)
    else:
        <error>
```

I am a django/python newbie, and would appreciate some help to debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in how templates resolve variables.  Inside a template `foo.bar` is not at all the same as in python `foo.bar`.  The template lookup syntax actaully wraps a slightly complex lookup sequence that attempts to figure out if you mean a dictionary lookup, an attribute, a callable attribute, an array index, etc.

In your case in a template when you directly write `quizform.ans1` it works because that actually ends up resolving to a dictionary lookup on the fields dict.  This is because django forms define the following magic method:

```
def __getitem__(self, name):
    "Returns a BoundField with the given name."
    try:
        field = self.fields[name]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError('Key %r not found in Form' % name)
    return BoundField(self, field, name)
```

The python `__getitem__` magic method is what allows non-dictionary classes to act like dictionaries.

Long story short...

```
@register.filter
def lookup(f, name):
    try:        
        return f[name]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

Should work better, (I haven't confirmed it).  Notice I changed the name of your filter...the old name isn't really appropriate with the fact that it's now causing a dictionary rather than attribute lookup.